# How to dump the xml of the android layout of android activity on running app

Tags: android, xml, debugging, layout

***Problem Description:***

I am debuggin an android app that is written by another developer. The layout of the screen is constructed via xml and several stuff are added dynamically. The code is a prototype code with no comments or naming conventions to understand  what's happening, or what variable does what.

***Question***

Is there a way to, when running the app, dump the xml layout as it is shown on the screen? That is retreive the xml layout that is dynamically constructed, in order to check variable and view's names?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found it inside the DDMS, there is a button called "DUMP view hierarchy for UI Automator" the button is next to the screenshot. And it will dump the xml to be used for automation testing.